# Antd Design EditableRow not changing buttons from "edit" to "save" and "cancel"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Im using Antd library and i can't seem to find where i have the bug.

**This is my EditableTableCell component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Form } from '@ant-design/compatible';
import '@ant-design/compatible/assets/index.css';
import { Input, InputNumber, Select, DatePicker } from "antd";
import moment from "moment";
import {EditableContext} from "./EditableTableRow";

const FormItem = Form.Item;
const Option = Select.Option;
class EditableTableCell extends Component {
    getInput = (record, dataIndex, title, getFieldDecorator) => {
        switch (this.props.inputType) {
            case "number":
                return (
                    <FormItem style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                        {getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
                            rules: [
                                {
                                    required: true,
                                    message: `Please Input ${title}!`
                                }
                            ],
                            initialValue: record[dataIndex]
                        })(
                            <InputNumber formatter={value => value} parser={value => value} />
                        )}
                    </FormItem>
                );
            case "date":
                return (
                    <FormItem style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                        {getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
                            initialValue: moment(record[dataIndex], this.dateFormat)
                        })(<DatePicker format={this.dateFormat} />)}
                    </FormItem>
                );
            case "select":
                return (
                    <FormItem style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                        {getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
                            initialValue: record[dataIndex]
                        })(
                            <Select style={{ width: 150 }}>
                                {[...Array(11).keys()]
                                    .filter(x => x > 0)
                                    .map(c => `Product ${c}`)
                                    .map((p, index) => (
                                        <Option value={p} key={index}>
                                            {p}
                                        </Option>
                                    ))}
                            </Select>
                        )}
                    </FormItem>
                );
            default:
                return (
                    <FormItem style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                        {getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
                            rules: [
                                {
                                    required: true,
                                    message: `Please Input ${title}!`
                                }
                            ],
                            initialValue: record[dataIndex]
                        })(<Input />)}
                    </FormItem>
                );
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { editing, dataIndex, title, inputType, record, index,...restProps} = this.props;
        return (
           <EditableContext.Consumer>
               {form => {
                   const { getFieldDecorator } = form;
                   return (
                       <td {...restProps}>
                           {editing ?
                               this.getInput(record, dataIndex, title, getFieldDecorator)
                               : restProps.children}
                       </td>
                   );
               }}
           </EditableContext.Consumer>
        );
    }
}

export default EditableTableCell;
```

**This is my EditableTableCell component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Form} from '@ant-design/compatible';

export const EditableContext = React.createContext();
class EditableTableRow extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <EditableContext.Provider value={this.props.form}>
                <tr {...this.props} />
            </EditableContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default EditableTableRow=Form.create()(EditableTableRow);
```

**This is my ProductsPage component im having bug in**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button, Layout, notification, Popconfirm, Space, Table,Typography} from "antd";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {Content} from "antd/es/layout/layout";
import EditableTableRow, {EditableContext} from "../components/EditableTableRow";
import EditableTableCell from "../components/EditableTableCell";
import API from "../server-apis/api";
import {employeesDataColumns} from "../tableColumnsData/employeesDataColumns";
import {CheckCircleFilled, InfoCircleFilled} from "@ant-design/icons";


class ProductsPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            editingKey: "",
            errorMessage: "",
         
        }
    }
    columns = [
        ...employeesDataColumns,
        {
            title: "Actions",
            dataIndex: "actions",
            width: "10%",
            render: (text, record) => {
                const editable = this.isEditing(record);
                return editable ? (
                    <span>
                                <EditableContext.Consumer>
                                  {form => (<a onClick={() => this.saveData(form, record.username)} style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>Save</a>)}
                                </EditableContext.Consumer>
                                <a onClick={this.cancel}>Cancel</a>
                            </span>
                ) : (
                    <Space size="middle">
                        <a onClick={() => this.edit(record.username)}>Edit</a>
                        <Popconfirm title="Are you sure you want to delete this product?"
                                    onConfirm={() => this.remove(record.username)}>
                            <a style={{color:"red"}}>Delete</a>
                        </Popconfirm>
                    </Space>
                );
            },
        }
    ];

    isEditing = (record) => {
        return record.username === this.state.editingKey;
    };

    edit(username) {
    
        this.setState({editingKey:username});
    }

    cancel = () => {
        this.setState({ editingKey: ""});
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        const token="Bearer "+ JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
        API.get(`users/all`,{ headers: { Authorization: token}})
            .then(res => {
                // console.log(res.data._embedded.productList);
                const employees = res.data._embedded.employeeInfoDtoList;
                this.setState({loading: false,data:employees });
            })
    }
    async remove(username) {
        const token="Bearer "+ JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
        API.delete(`/users/${username}`,{ headers: { Authorization: token}})
            .then(() => {
                let updatedProducts = [...this.state.data].filter(i => i.username !== username);
                this.setState({data: updatedProducts});
                this.successfullyAdded("Employee is deleted. It wont have any access to the website anymore.")
            }).catch(()=>this.errorHappend("Failed to delete"));
    }

    hasWhiteSpace(s) {
        return /\s/g.test(s);
    }
    saveData(form,username) {
        form.validateFields((error, row) => {
            if (error) {
                return;
            }
            const newData = [...this.state.data];
            const index = newData.findIndex(item => username === item.username);
            const item = newData[index];
            newData.splice(index, 1, {
                ...item,
                ...row
            });
            const token="Bearer "+ JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
            const response = API.put(`/users/${username}/update`, row,{ headers: { Authorization: token}})
                .then((response) => {
                    this.setState({ data: newData, editingKey: ""});
                    this.successfullyAdded("Empolyee info is updated")
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
                    this.errorHappend("Failed to save changes.")
                    console.error('There was an error!', error);
                });
        });
    }
    successfullyAdded = (message) => {
        notification.info({
            message: `Notification`,
            description:message,
            placement:"bottomRight",
            icon: <CheckCircleFilled style={{ color: '#0AC035' }} />
        });
    };
    errorHappend = (error) => {
        notification.info({
            message: `Notification`,
            description:
                `There was an error! ${error}`,
            placement:"bottomRight",
            icon: <InfoCircleFilled style={{ color: '#f53333' }} />
        });
    };
    render() {
        const components = {
            body: {
                row: EditableTableRow,
                cell: EditableTableCell
            }
        };
        const columns = this.columns.map(col => {
            if (!col.editable) {
                return col;
            }
            return {
                ...col,
                onCell: record => {
                    const checkInput = index => {
                        switch (index) {
                            case "price":
                                return "number";
                            default:
                                return "text";
                        }
                    };
                    return {
                        record,
                        // inputType: col.dataIndex === "age" ? "number" : "text",
                        inputType: checkInput(col.dataIndex),
                        dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
                        title: col.title,
                        editing: this.isEditing(record)
                    };
                }
            };
        });
        const { data, loading } = this.state;
        return (
            <Layout>
                <div>
                    <Link to="/add-product">
                        <Button style={{float:"right", background: "#0AC035",marginBottom:"1em", marginTop:"1em" }}
                                type="primary">New emplyee</Button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <Content>
                
                    <Table components={components} bordered dataSource={data} columns={columns} loading={loading} rowKey={data.username} rowClassName="editable-row"/>
                </Content>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}

export default ProductsPage;
```

This is the bug I'm having:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmqmK.png)

And i want to have this result like its shown in Antd docs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSgk1.png)

Id really appreciate if you take a look and help me figure out where im wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Solution:**
I find the issue. In render where you map the columns, you just return the column if it's not an editable column. You can check the code below. I added a check if it's `dataIndex === 'actions'`, then return the following code:
Please Follow the link:
https://react-ts-v3fbst.stackblitz.io

**Changes:**

**1.In columns, i remove the render function from the action object:**

```
{
      title: 'Actions',
      dataIndex: 'actions',
      width: '10%',
},
```

**2. In render function where you map the columns, add the following code before this condition `if(!col.editable) {`,:**

```
if (col.dataIndex === 'actions') {
    return {
        ...col,
        render: (text, record) => {
            const editable = this.isEditing(record);
            return editable ? (
                <span>
                    <EditableContext.Consumer>
                        {(form) => (
                            <a onClick={() => this.saveData(form, record.username)} style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>
                                Save
                            </a>
                        )}
                    </EditableContext.Consumer>
                    <a onClick={this.cancel}>Cancel</a>
                </span>
            ) : (
                <Space size='middle'>
                    <a onClick={() => this.edit(record.username)}>Edit</a>
                    <Popconfirm title='Are you sure you want to delete this product?' onConfirm={() => this.remove(record.username)}>
                        <a style={{ color: 'red' }}>Delete</a>
                    </Popconfirm>
                </Space>
            );
        }
    };
}
```

---

When you click on edit, you set the username as key for that particular row for editing, make sure you have `username` in each record. I tested this using the following data:

```
const data = [
    { id: 8, name: 'baun', model: '2022', color: 'black', price: 358, quantity: 3, username: 'brvim' },
    { id: 3, name: 'galileo', model: '20221', color: 'white', price: 427, quantity: 7, username: 'john' }
];
```

Most important, you should select that attribute as key that is unique in all records. As you are using `username`, i don't know what is your business logic or data looks like, but technically each record can have same `username`. So you must select something that would always be unique in your complete data.

Comment: username is unique, but as you may see in the picture i have posted when i click edit whole row get editable but im not getting any changes for the "Actions" column. It should change from "Edit" to "Save" and "Cancel" buttons when row is editable

Comment: I have tested your code, When i click on edit, it does show Save and cancel button. It all works as expected. Can you please create a sandbox for your problem/program?

Comment: Yes, of course! This is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lqt1rl?file=index.js

Comment: If its taking too long to load the project you can you this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-sfxgf8?file=index.tsx

Comment: @brvim thanks for creating sandbox for your code. I have updated my answer. I found the issue that was not changing the buttons in action column.  Hope this solution resolve your problem/issue.

Comment: Hey im really, really sorry to bother you and im grateful for you help, but i can not find the changes you've made. Can you please tell me what did you changed in the code?

Comment: To save the changes in the code, you need to click "Fork" in the top bar...

Comment: https://react-ts-v3fbst.stackblitz.io